# problem with character passing through objects / Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My character can move into other objects only when he moves in both directions. I left the my character code and photo of my question [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsHHO.png). I would be happy if you help.and i also played with all the colliders and filters of my character and the floor my character is in but still not resolved

```
float moveSpeed = 6f;           
float rotationSpeed = 6f;       
Vector3 moveDirection;

Rigidbody rb;


void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Move();
}

void Move()
{
    float hAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float vAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(hAxis, 0f, vAxis);
    rb.position += movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Rigidbody.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html) will teleport the rigidbody to the given position. This will still trigger the collision events but will not allow your Rigidbody to actually stop in front of the other colliders.

Rather use [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)

> Rigidbody.MovePosition moves a Rigidbody and complies with the interpolation settings. When Rigidbody interpolation is enabled, Rigidbody.MovePosition creates a smooth transition between frames.

Which should now take the collisions into account and stop outside of the other colliders.

```
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

or I think directly using the [`rb.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) should also do it

```
var velocity = movement * moveSpeed;
// For keeping the Y (gravity) velocity
velocity.y = rb.velocity.y;
rb.velocity = velocity;
```

---

If you want/need to be totally sure you could also use [`Physics.ComputePenetration`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ComputePenetration.html) in combination with a [`Rigidbody.Sweeptest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.SweepTest.html) which allows you to check whether the rigidbody **would** hit anything on its way and if so move it just back far enough to be not inside the hit collider.

---

Just a general hint you will want to avoid being faster while moving diagonal by using

```
Vector3 movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(new Vector3(hAxis, 0f, vAxis), 1f);
```

which will make sure the vector is normalized to a magnitude of `1` in case both inputs together would result in a vector with a higher magnitude.

Comment: yes it worked but in any collider merge the character stays directly where it is. How can I make it move towards the empty space when I diagonally press it?

Answer (score 0):

Add collider to both character and objects.
Make sure the character is placed correctly placed in the scene.
Also make sure that character has rigidbody.